# How to make vehicles move at random speed in SUMO?

Tags: simulator, traffic, sumo

How can I make vehicles move at a random speed in SUMO? The speed should be different every time the simulation starts.

Comment: This can be done in SUMO alone. No need to use Veins

Comment: Hi Sir, I have implemented my own algorithm for information dissemination in the example scenario of erlangen provided by you in veins. I need to check my algorithm at various traffic scenarios. for example : randomly sparse vehicles , overtaking vehicles , random speed of each vehicle. i have studied sumo vtype parameters and flow parameters but couldn't succed in getting a new random flow everytime. Source and destination are fixed as in example. Kindly help.

Comment: You might be running SUMO with the same pseudorandom number generator seed (the --seed option, if I recall correctly). Try running the SUMO simulation directly from the command line (i.e., without OMNeT++) while manually setting different seeds. You should see different behavior of vehicles.

Comment: @ChristophSommer can you please inform that if I run SUMO simulation directly, then how OMNeT++ (and veins) will be able to detect SUMO because in this case, I assume we don't have to run sumo-launchd.py. Many thanks.

Comment: @YasirSaleem this seems like a different question to the one asked here. Would you mind opening a new thread for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the departspeed="random" attribute when defining a new vehicle or flow but this influences only the initial speed. Be sure to use the "--random" option when running sumo to get a different random seed each time. For variances in maximum speed (and maybe other vehicle type parameters such as acceleration and deceleration) have a look at the script [createVehTypeDistributions.py](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Misc#createVehTypeDistributions.py). There is also a general overview of [sources of randomness](http://%20https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Randomness) in sumo.